# Distance of a d dimensional point in a hypercube

Tags: probability, vectors

Assume a particle X in $d$-dimensional hypercube. Each dimension is independent of another and the particle's position is distributed uniformly in each.

A distance measure of $D = \frac{1}{2} \max\limits_{i\in 1\cdots d} \lvert \frac{1}{2} - X_i\rvert$ is computed

$P(D >a) = p(\frac{1}{2} \max\limits_{i\in 1\cdots d} \lvert \frac{1}{2} - X_i\rvert >a) = p(\max\limits_{i\in 1\cdots d} \lvert \frac{1}{2} - X_i\rvert > 2a)= 1- p(\max\limits_{i\in 1\cdots d} \lvert \frac{1}{2} - X_i\rvert \leq 2a) =
1 - \prod\limits_i p(\lvert \frac{1}{2} - X_i \rvert \leq 2a))$

$ = \prod\limits_i 2 p(X_i-\frac{1}{2} \leq 2a | X_i >\frac{1}{2}) = 1-(8a)^d$

Am I goin wrong somewhere?

Comment: Why is the probability that the maximum over dimensions of ${1 \over 2} - X_i$ equal to the product of the probabilities that *each* dimension is greater than $a$?  An imagine that $d \to \infty$.  Then surely the probability that the particle deviates from ${1 \over 2}$  on *at least one* dimension gets higher and higher (approaching 1.0).  However, your formula states the probability is the product of a large (infinite) number of terms, each of which is less than 1.0, so that product gets *smaller* (approaching 0.).  Rethink what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. So it would be accurate to say $p(D>a) = p(\frac{1}{2} max |\frac{1}{2} - X_i| > a) = p(max |\frac{1}{2} - X_i| > 2a)$, but I dont know how to proceed from here. Any hints would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the particle deviates from ${1 \over 2}$ on *at least one* dimension is 1 - probability that *none* of them do.

Answer (score 0):

The event $D<a$ represents the fact that the particle is inside a hypercube centered at $(1/2,...,1/2)$ with edges of length $4a$. This hypercube has volume $(4a)^d$. Given the uniform distribution inside the original (unit, I suppose) hypercube, the probability of that event is the ratio of volumes:
$$
P(D<a)=\frac{(4a)^d}{1^d}=(4a)^d.
$$
Therefore
$$
P(D>a)=1-(4a)^d.
$$
(of course if $a\geq1/4$ the probability is $0$).